# After I conneted the UIVIew to my code,it crashed,why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xib

I press on CONTROL and drag the UIImageVIew and UILabel which is in AppView.xib to my code file named "AppVIew.h". Before I connect the two UI widgets it ran ok ,I want to know the reasons leading to the crash.Very thanks for your answers.
@property

The code as following:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AppView : UIView

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *icon;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *name;

+ (id)AppViewWithIcon:(NSString *)icon Name:(NSString *)name;
@end

#import "AppView.h"
@implementation AppView

+ (id)AppViewWithIcon:(NSString *)icon Name:(NSString *)name{
    AppView *view = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AppView" owner:nil options:nil][0];
    NSLog(@"%@",view);
    return view;

}
```

the errors as following:

```
1.Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0X0)
2.2016-03-27 18:53:36.804 05-九宫格[4302:283744] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x7fca52c1a1c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key icon.'

*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101630d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001010a4deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001016309c9 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   Foundation                          0x0000000100c6f19b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288
4   UIKit                               0x0000000101db07fb -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010156a890 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
6   UIKit                               0x0000000101daf1de -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864
7   UIKit                               0x0000000101db1415 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 223
8   05-‰πùÂÆ´Ê†º                        0x0000000100ba1490 +[AppView AppViewWithIcon:Name:] + 160
9   05-‰πùÂÆ´Ê†º                        0x0000000100ba0cae -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 206
10  UIKit                               0x0000000101b81984 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
11  UIKit                               0x0000000101b81cd3 -[UIViewController view] + 27
12  UIKit                               0x0000000101a57fb4 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 61
13  UIKit                               0x0000000101a5869d -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282
14  UIKit                               0x0000000101a6a180 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
15  UIKit                               0x00000001019deed9 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4131
16  UIKit                               0x00000001019e5568 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1769
17  UIKit                               0x00000001019e2714 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
18  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010444f8c8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
19  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010444f741 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 178
20  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010444faca -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101556301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010154c22c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010154b6e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010154b0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
25  UIKit                               0x00000001019e1f21 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
26  UIKit                               0x00000001019e6f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
27  05-‰πùÂÆ´Ê†º                        0x0000000100ba195f main + 111
28  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000103e0a92d start + 1
29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

(lldb)

Comment: Make sure that there aren't any 'ghost' outlets connected to your xib.
You can remove all outlets, and re-add them one by one to make sure that you don't have any outlet which references non existing UI items.

Answer (score 0):

Check if their are any previous outlets that have been deleted from within the storyboard, by either checking the view controller inspector and referencing outlets for any outlets that may contradict the ones you have made as well as the UIView/UILabel.